# I need insert some PHP code in style sheet

Tags: php, css

In my css

```
div.image {
   width:<?php echo get_image_size( $size[1] ); ?>px;
}
```

The size is stored in an array so i called $size[1] to here...

I am beginner in php...

any one pls help?

Comment: what is your reasoning to do this? Are you defining image dimensions from database? I wouldn't mix CSS with PHP, if you are, you need to re-think what you are doing.

Comment: The better solution is to set the with direct on the image ;) <img with="" style="witdth" />

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to use like this

1. change your css file as css.php, and use stylesheet include like this

   `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css.php?opt1=<?php echo get_image_size($size[1] ); ?>" />`
2. In css.php file

   `div.image {
      width:<?php echo $_GET['opt1']; ?>px;
   }`

try this

Answer (score 8):

Better solution is to set a header for the css / php file in my example cssfile.php:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Then you can use the php file as style.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="cssfile.php?param=1" />
```

Then you should get the output on your site. But with that solution you should be very careful if you have a lot of traffic. On every site call your PHP interpreter is used to deliver that file.

Answer (score 4):

Yes for this particular instance if you just need php on this one line it is best to insert in the head of your html instead of having php make a whole css file for you.

```
<style type="text/css">
  div.image {
   width:<?php echo get_image_size( $size[1] ); ?>px;
  }    
</style>
```

PHP should NOT be creating your static assets unless absolutely necessary.  You will notice performance hit if traffic gets high.

Answer (score 3):

Change the extension to .php and then in your stylesheet put:

```
<?php header("Content-type: text/css"); ?>
```

Then you can use PHP inside your stylesheet.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should use this:

```
<div class="image">
  <img src="image.gif" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div.image img{
   width: 100%
}
```

The problem with putting style inside html is that everything get messed. You should try to separate html from css and js as much as possible.

Also, from my expirience, this is not a good practice to use php in css or js files.

Consider reviewing your html layout to optimize this.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to move that particular piece out of the .css file, and insert it in a PHP document that has access to the get_image_size() function. For example, you may have a template that is parsed as the header. You could then surround this piece in `<style>` tags.