# PHP and CSS in a Stylesheet with Custom Fields

Tags: php, html, css, custom-fields, advanced-custom-fields

I've set up a PHP stylesheet and it's working when I add CSS.

```
.test123 {color:red;} \\ this is working fine.
```

Now I want to add something like this:

```
.test123 {color:<?php [php code here that links to a custom field] ?>;} \\ this is my goal
```

I have tested different PHP for custom fields like:

```
.test123 { color: <?php the_field('color');?> ; } \\ linked to color picker of ACF
```

...but every php code inside the CSS always returns this message:

> "Fatal error:Call to undefined function"

I don't understand yet what I am doing wrong here.

So this is what I've set up now:

Working version of **stylephp.php** >>

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');

   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "red";
?>

.test321 { 
color:  <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}

.test3210 { 
color: <?php echo $brandColor; ?>;
}
```

Working version of **functions.php** >>

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
}

function add_stylesheet_to_head()
{
    echo "<link href='http://[my test website address is normally here]/stylephp.php' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>";
}
add_action('wp_head', 'add_stylesheet_to_head');

?>
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

---

I've updated the stylephp.php file, but `<?php the_field( "color" ); ?>` is still not working with ACF.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/css');
if( function_exists('get_field'))
    return;
if( function_exists('the_field'))
    return;
function is_field_group_exists($value, $type='post_title') {
        $exists = false;
        if ($field_groups = get_posts(array('post_type'=>'acf-field-group'))) {
            foreach ($field_groups as $field_group) {
                if ($field_group->$type == $value) {
                    $exists = true;
                }
            }
        }
        return $exists;
    }


   $brandColor = "#990000";
   $linkColor = "red";



?>


.test321 { 
color:  <?php echo $linkColor; ?>;
}

.test3210 { 
color: <?php echo $brandColor; ?>;
}

.test12345 { 
color: <?php the_field( "color" ); ?>;
}
```

Comment: Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10333295/i-need-insert-some-php-code-in-style-sheet)

Comment: The error says it all `Call to undefined function`. I don't see anywhere in your code where you have a function called the_field.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply! I have installed ACF for Wordpress so I thought this ACF function is called automatically.

Comment: What would you expect when you call an undefined function? Not a working code, at least... First define that function and then ask for help.